# Making WebView audio play in background

Tags: android, audio, webview

I am making an android app for my website. It has some videos which are somewhat like podcasts. I want the app to be able to play the audio in the background when the user either locks the screen or is using other applications. To achieve this, I have a WebView in place. To provide the above mentioned functionality, I tried to use a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK in the activity. This only continues to play the audio when the screen is locked, but not when the home button is pressed (ie. in the background). Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: I am getting answers for playing audio with media player. I am looking to play videos on the webview and continue playing the audio in the background.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I fixed it with using a service anyway.

Comment: I've implemented a separate service to run the webView and I still have this issue. Are there any more clues on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want your app to keep running the Audio even if it is in Background, You have to run the Mediaplayer in a `Separate Service.`

This service will keep on Running even the app goes to background or comes back.
You can even write a sticky service to keep running(with foreground as true) if the app gets killed.

Comment: But I thought you can't run WebView in a seperate Service thread because it is a UI element.

Comment: @NathanMatthews Are you pausing that Audio somewhere in onPause method. ideally it should continue to play if you have just pressed the home button.

Answer (score 0):

You should use android service to play the music independent of your activity.Please look at this example:

Here is my Android Service class:

```
class MusicService extends Service implements OnCompletionListener {
  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.s);// raw/s.mp3
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
      mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
  }

  public void onDestroy() {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
      mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    mediaPlayer.release();
}

  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer) {
    stopSelf();
  }

}
```

Here is Activity:

```
public class MusicActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

  Button startPlaybackButton, stopPlaybackButton;
  Intent playbackServiceIntent;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    startPlaybackButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.StartPlaybackButton);
    stopPlaybackButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.StopPlaybackButton);

    startPlaybackButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    stopPlaybackButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    playbackServiceIntent = new Intent(this,MusicService.class);
  }

  public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == startPlaybackButton) {
      startService(playbackServiceIntent);
      finish();
    } else if (v == stopPlaybackButton) {
      stopService(playbackServiceIntent);
      finish();
    }
  }
}
```

Please do not forget to add the service in your manifest file :

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".services.MusicService" />
```

Comment: I am looking to play videos on the webview and continue playing the audio in the background.